# Combining graphics & lists / tables

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

I have:

[image]

created with:

```
With[{stdOpt = {InterpolationOrder -> 0, 
GridLines -> {Range[10], Range[10]}, 
GridLinesStyle -> Directive[GrayLevel[0.8], Dashed], 
Joined -> True, AspectRatio -> 1}}, 
ListPlot[{0}, stdOpt, PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {0, 10}}, Axes -> False,
Frame -> False, Epilog -> {

Black, Opacity[1.0],

Text[Style[1, Large, FontFamily -> "Times"], {0.5, 0.5}, 
 FormatType -> Bold],
Text[Style[2, Large, FontFamily -> "Times"], {0.5, 1.5}, 
 FormatType -> Bold],
Text[Style[3, Large, FontFamily -> "Times"], {0.5, 2.5}, 
 FormatType -> Bold],
Text[Style[4, Large, FontFamily -> "Times"], {0.5, 3.5}, 
 FormatType -> Bold],
Text[Style[5, Large, FontFamily -> "Times"], {0.5, 4.5}, 
 FormatType -> Bold],
Text[Style[6, Large, FontFamily -> "Times"], {0.5, 5.5}, 
 FormatType -> Bold],
Text[Style[7, Large, FontFamily -> "Times"], {0.5, 6.5}, 
 FormatType -> Bold],
Text[Style[8, Large, FontFamily -> "Times"], {0.5, 7.5}, 
 FormatType -> Bold],
Text[Style[9, Large, FontFamily -> "Times"], {0.5, 8.5}, 
 FormatType -> Bold],
Text[Style[10, Large, FontFamily -> "Times"], {0.5, 9.5}, 
 FormatType -> Bold]

}]]
```

and I would like to place (& correctly align) a column of numbers (from pre-made lists) for each of the 10 columns (rather than the manully placed numbers as they appear above).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Random `premade` list:

```
SeedRandom@1;
m = 10; (* size of the grid *)
premade = RandomInteger[10, {m, m}];
```

column coordinates:

```
col[n_] := Table[{n - 0.5, i - 0.5}, {i, 1, m}]
```

And the wanted `Graphics`:

```
Graphics[
 {Table[
    Text[Style[premade[[#, i]], Large, FontFamily -> "Times"],col[i][[#]]] & /@ Range@m,
       {i, 1, m}]},
  GridLines -> {Range@m, Range@m}, PlotRange -> {{0, m}, {0, m}},
  Axes -> False, Frame -> True, GridLinesStyle -> Directive[GrayLevel[0.8], Dashed]]
```

[image]

Comment: @ Öskå, fantastic! - Just what I was after - super speedy reply too! :)

Comment: You are welcome :) Check the edit for your _"for each of the 10 columns"_ part of your question :)

Comment: @martin do you still need the pink `Rectangle`s?

Comment: @ Öskå, not just yet ;)

Comment: I can edit with a few more lines placing random rectangles if it helps

Comment: @ Öskå, I would ultimately like to make grid interactive by clicking on a square & highlighting that number (& others that are say, double that number within the grid, and then double that number, etc...), but I will probably create another (few) post(s) to this effect! :)

Answer (score 3):

```
SeedRandom@1;
m = 10;(*size of the grid*)

premade = Map[Text[Style[#, Large, FontFamily -> "Times"]] &,  RandomInteger[10, {m, m}], {2}];
Grid[premade, Frame -> All, FrameStyle -> Dashed, ItemSize -> 2.5]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: @ belisarius, thanks for your 'slimmer' version (in terms of amount of code needed) - very useful from a learning point of view :)